# Add Button to create a row and delete to remove a row in a table in swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I need a Jtable having Add Button on the header.When add is clicked..then it must add a row containing 4 columns of 3 textfields and delete button. When delete button is clicked, then the corresponding row should deleted.. Thanks in advance..

```
public class UserTableInfo {
private JFrame frame;
private JTable CompTable = null;
private PanelTableModel CompModel = null;
private JButton delButton=null;
private JButton button=null;
public static void main(String args[]) {
try {
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
} catch (Exception fail) {
}
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
new UserTableInfo().makeUI();
}
});    }
public void makeUI() {
CompTable = CreateCompTable();
JScrollPane CompTableScrollpane = new JScrollPane(CompTable,
JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
JPanel bottomPanel = CreateBottomPanel();
frame = new JFrame("Comp Table Test");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.add(CompTableScrollpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
frame.setLocation(150, 150);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}public JTable CreateCompTable() {
CompModel = new PanelTableModel();
button=new JButton("Add Row");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
CompModel.addRow();
}
});        
JTable table = new JTable(CompModel);
table.setRowHeight(new CompCellPanel().getPreferredSize().height);
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING, 5, 0));
header.add(button);
PanelCellEditorRenderer PanelCellEditorRenderer = new
PanelCellEditorRenderer();
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, PanelCellEditorRenderer);
table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, PanelCellEditorRenderer);
return table;
}    public JPanel CreateBottomPanel() {
delButton=new JButton("Exit");
delButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
Object source = ae.getSource();
if (source == delButton) {
System.exit(1);
}           
}
});        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
panel.add(delButton);
return panel;
}
}
class PanelCellEditorRenderer extends AbstractCellEditor implements
TableCellRenderer, TableCellEditor {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private CompCellPanel renderer = new CompCellPanel();
private CompCellPanel editor = new CompCellPanel();
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object
value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
renderer.setComp((Comp) value);
return renderer;
}
@Override
public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object
value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
editor.setComp((Comp) value);
return editor;
}
@Override
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
return null;
}
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent) {
return true;
}
@Override
public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) {
return false;
}
}
class PanelTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
return 1;
}
public void addRow() {
super.addRow(new Object[]{new Comp("")});
}
}
class Comp {
public String upper;
public Comp(String upper) {
this.upper = upper;
}
}
class CompCellPanel extends JPanel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JLabel label = new JLabel();
private JTextField upperField = new JTextField();
private JButton removeButton = new JButton("remove");
CompCellPanel() {
setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
JTable table = (JTable)
SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JTable.class, (Component) e.getSource());
int row = table.getEditingRow();
table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row);
}        });
upperField.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE,            upperField.getPreferredSize().height) );
add(upperField);
label.setMaximumSize(getMaximumSize());
add(label);
add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
add(removeButton);
}
public void setComp(Comp Comp) {
upperField.setText(Comp.upper);
}    }
```

Comment: I assume you already tried something. Please post your best effort here as well and not just your requirement

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks. 3) What is your question?

Comment: pls provide me code for having buttons in cells of table with logic to remove corresponding rows..

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you extend a `AbstractTableModel` and use that to display your data. You can make an ArrayList of your data and add/remove from that. The TableModel will update the Table automatically when the ArrayList is changed. The ArrayList contains a class which has all the data that you would have in a row. See the Java Tutorials example from Oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java

For custom cells, you can detect from the TableModel which column the cell is in and update its content accordingly.